# can't Http request on Android widget button.

Tags: android, http, request, httprequest

It's really weird. 
code is simple. 
when clicking button, it goes getNaverHtmlOn functon which request to website.

but there, when my phone is not plugged in to power supply, 
it didn't work. but when I plugged in to my phone, it works.

and, when my phone is not plugged in, 
press button and launch app, then http request work

how can I have my http request done without plugging in to my phone

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (SYNC_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        Log.e("main","clicked");
        Toast.makeText(context,"1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        new Thread() {
        public void run() {
             getNaverHtmlOn();
        }
    }.start();
        Log.e("main","clicked333");


    }
  }



private String getNaverHtmlOn() {
        String naverHtml = "";

        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try{
            URL url = new URL("https://xxxxx.herokuapp.com/xxxx?xxx=015EF&xxx=0");
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            con.setReadTimeout(10000);

            isr = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            String str = null;

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(con != null){
                try{con.disconnect();}catch(Exception e){}
            }

            if(isr != null){
                try{isr.close();}catch(Exception e){}
            }

            if(br != null){
                try{br.close();}catch(Exception e){}
            }
        }
        return naverHtml;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when my phone is not plugged in to power supply, it didn't work. but when I plugged in to my phone, it works.

This may be a hardware problem. It seems like your phone is in power save mode. Try trun off that in system settings.

Or run your application on another phone to make sure it's a hardware problem or a weird software bug.